# Android NDK error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load vlccorev6: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android-ndk

This error torture me more than three months.

I build ffmpeg and vlc library, two versions compiled, one is vlccorev6 and ffmpegv6 for the devices without Neon Support,  and the other vlccore and ffmpeg for the devices with Neon Support.

I received many crash report from some devices(mainly from Galaxy Y (GT-S5360) and Galaxy Ace (GT-S5830i)) like this:

Android NDK error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load vlccorev6: findLibrary returned null

Now i bought a GT-S5360,  but runs OK...

What can i do?

Below is ffmpeg's configure and VLC's Android.mk:

**ffmpeg Configure:**

```
./configure --target-os=linux \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --extra-libs="-lgcc" \
    --arch=arm \
    --disable-debug \
    --cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
    --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
    --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
    --extra-cflags="-I../ -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums  -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS" \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --extra-ldflags="-L../lame -Wl,-T,$PREBUILT/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/ldscripts/armelf_linux_eabi.x -Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/crtbegin.o $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/crtend.o -lc -lm -ldl" \

    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG


$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar d libavcodec/libavcodec.a inverse.o

$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib  -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib  -z,noexecstack -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $PREFIX/libffmpeg.so libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a  -lc -lm -ldl -llog  --warn-once  --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/i686-android-linux/4.4.3/libgcc.a

}

CPU=armv6
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-marm -march=$CPU"
PREFIX=./android/$CPU 
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=--disable-neon
```

**VLC Android.mk**

```
APP_OPTIM := release
OPT_CFLAGS := -O3 -mlong-calls -fstrict-aliasing -fprefetch-loop-arrays -ffast-math

BUILD_WITH_NEON := 0


OPT_CPPFLAGS := $(OPT_CLFAGS)

APP_CFLAGS := $(APP_CFLAGS) $(OPT_CFLAGS)
APP_CPPFLAGS := $(APP_CPPFLAGS) $(OPT_CPPFLAGS) 

APP_STL := gnustl_static

APP_ABI := armeabi
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried load lib by this:

```
static {
    System.load("/data/data/[your.class.path]/lib/[lib_file].so");
}
```

hope it fix your problem.

Comment: it's better check the lib folder by using "adb shell" to load the file properly.